# www.pythonanywhere.com: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, массивы

Мой код:

```
control_quantity = []
found = False
message_id = input("Message.chat.id = ")

for i in control_quantity:
  if i[0] == message_id:
    i[1] += 1
    found = True

if found == False:
  control_quantity.append([message_id, 1])
```

Во время хостинга телеграм бота на сайте www.pythonanywhere.com вылетает ошибка:

```
**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**
```

Попробовал запустить программу с компа, получилось. А на этом сайте вылетает такая ошибка.
Что мне сделать чтобы ошибка не вылетала и почему она может вылетать?

Для проверки, мой код здесь: https://repl.it/repls/BrilliantFrigidScientists

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите `Traceback` (полный текст ошибки). Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Очевидно, ваш реальный код отличается от того фрагмента, который вы привели, и ошибка содержится именно в той части кода, который мы не видим. Так как же мы можем вам помочь?